# didSelectRowAtIndexPath on TableView

Tags: swift

not sure what I am doing wrong. I get this error:

> fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional
>   value in this line `self.profileImage.image = UIImage(data: data)`

after I `didSelectRowAtIndexPath`. I dont want to send anything as the sender, but when I try to performSegueWithIdentifier it seems to be trying to get that cell? Why would it call configureCell function again after I select it?

> ViewController

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
        victim = friends[indexPath.row] as Friend!
        DataService.shared.setVictim(victim!)
        print("It got here with friend: \(victim!)")
        performSegueWithIdentifier("commentFromSegue", sender: nil)
}
```

> FriendsTableViewCell

```
   class FriendTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

    @IBOutlet weak var friendName: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var profileImage: UIImageView!

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        // Initialization code
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        layer.cornerRadius = 5.0
    }

    func configureCell(friend: Friend) {
        let url = NSURL(string: friend.profileImg)
        if let data = NSData(contentsOfURL: url!) {
          self.profileImage.image = UIImage(data: data)
          // works if I comment out the above line. but does not show profile image
        }
        friendName.text = friend.friendName
        }
    }
```

Comment: It seems that `profileImage` is `nil`. Is the outlet properly connected in Interface Builder?

Comment: Ya its connected. It shows the profile image.

Comment: try to typing in the error log the next `po data`. Look what it will return

Comment: Set a breakpoint or insert a print line to check if `profileImage` is not `nil`

Comment: @iamalizade `data` is obviously not `nil` and `UIImage(data:)` would return `nil` if `data`could not be identified as image data. The result is no image will be displayed but the app wouldn't crash.

Comment: So weird. just don't understand why its going inside the configureCell function again after I select the cell. and why its nil.. data isnt nil. its the profileImage.image

Comment: The crucial object is the `UIImageView` instance, not it's `image` property.